# Where does the anglicisation "Ottoman" come from?

Tags: etymology, history, names, transliteration, anglicization

Wikipedia on Ottoman Empire gives its naming as coming from the [Ottoman Turkish language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_language), but on that very page, the name of the language is transliterated as *Lisân-ı Osmânî*. In Russian we call the empire and language "Османская"/-ий, also transliterating as "Osman[suffix]". The trail vanishes there... Were telephones that bad that the Turks said "Os" and the English heard "Otto"?

Comment: Looking through the other transliterations on that page, most are os-, but a few are otto-, especially Italian and French. But not German...

Comment: The British did have a tendency for anglicizing, the examples are rampant in Colonial India, Mumbai-Bombay/ Shimla-Simla.So the 'bad telephone line', could be closer to the truth than you think!

Comment: @PreetieSekhon With India and surrounds, I find /s/ and /sh/ are commonly confounded in transliteration. (Which could be a name for a new movie, a sequel.)

Comment: In Russian we have a similar problem with /kh/ and /gh/. So, e.g. Holland is Gollandia, etc. etc. etc. But there's probably an obvious explanation for that: in some Russian dialects /gh/ is pronounced as /kh/.

Comment: What about Banerjee and Bandhopadhyay?

Comment: The name in Arabic is Othman. Click on the Arabic audio icon to listen to the pronunciation: http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/othman

Comment: This only works for me in Google Chrome. To me sounds like a non-voiced /th/ with a hiss. A drunk /th/.

Comment: Evgeni, that sounds like a perfectly normal [θ] to me. No more drunk than any other [θ].

Comment: @BlessedGeek: why is the Arabic pronunciation any more important than the French or English when dealing with a Turkish name?

Comment: Arabic etymology is important in Turkish, Urdu, modern Parsi, modern Indonesian/Malay because of Islamisation, and therefore creolization of Arabic names and terms into those respective languages. And the deference of English/French to Arabic( or Hebrew) first due to familiarity and then corrupting the pronunciation along the way. Othman is an Arabic name to begin with. With any name of Arabic origin, I would tend to want to correlate the Turkish/Urdu/Parsi version back to the Arabic version, causing confusion along the way.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: that sounds like a version of the etymological fallacy. "The Arabic *Othman* was heard (and transliterated) by the Turks as *Osman* and by the Franks/Crusaders as *Otman* or *Ottoman*" would be quite a good answer, but you can't say Osman I himself mispronounced his name.

Comment: Pejoratives are seldom self-assigned.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: I do not understand your last comment. Are you seriously saying that Osman was mistaken when he pronounced his own name, merely because it was not the same as the Arabic version? Many American names have anglicised pronunciations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ottoman" comes from French. [OED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ottoman&searchmode=none) mentions that

> Byron used the more correct form **Othman**...

We see that pronunciation with /th/ or /s/ is closer to the original, but in some languages (French, Italian) the pronunciation is different.

Comment: I'd never guess that /th/ and /s/ sound similar!

Comment: This must reflect the state of ancient dentistry in the area.

Comment: It is very common for /th/ (as in English ‘thing’) to be pronounced and transcribed as /s/ by speakers who do not have the sound in their own language. Scandinavians, Germans, and the French do it all the time, as do the Chinese. Both sounds are fricatives produced in the far front of the mouth; only the exact place of articulation really differs (intradental vs. dental/alveolar).

Comment: The French tend to need to overcompensate their spelling, because of their tending to be "lazy" in pronunciation. Look at the word "ouille". Writing "ouil", they would refuse to pronounce the L. Even if doubling the L, still they would not pronounce the L. OK, why not end it with an E - that would force the to trail the L sound. But over time, they still ultimately dropped the L sound. There are just certain consonants the French would refuse to pronounce.

Answer (score 4):

Far from the Turks having said "Os" and the English having heard "Otto", it is the variation in pronunciation coupled with a lack of exact equivalents in English that resulted in the curious *spelling*.

There are several *s* sounds in Turkish, not one, and each of these may not be pronounced identically by Turkish, Arab and Persian speakers.

Arie S. Issar & Mattanyah Zohar, in their book *[Climate Change: Environment and History of the Near East](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=YdnfMxhDPp0C&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22S%20sound%22%20turkish)* provide a brief insight:

> The name "Ottoman" is derived from an 18th century "overcorrect" mispronunciation of the name of the founder, *Osman*, based on the Arab pronunciation *'Othman* (with a sound like the English "th") but difficult for Persian and Turkish speakers who prefer the /s/ sound. (footnote at p.228)

Comment: Arab speaker != Arabic speaker